# Formulation of a stepwise linear approximation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, linearization, approximation

I am currently trying to solve an MILP in Gurobi. Unfortunately, Gurobi does not support non-linear functions and I would like to do the following. I currently have the following constraint. It calculates the residual power of a machine $j$ at time $t$, where $\alpha$ is a parameter. Currently the relationship is linear:

$$degneration_{jt}=1-\alpha\cdot age_{jt}$$

But I would like to model such a progression
$$f(x)=e^{-x}$$
and would like to use a linear approximation for this. How would I have to model something like this, unfortunately I have no idea.

Comment: Does $f$ appear in the objective function (in which case we need to know whether you are maximizing or minimizing it) or in constraints?

Comment: @prubin I am sorry, the OP isn't clear enough. $f$ doesn't appear in either. It's just an example. Currently I have a linear relationship ship between $degneration$ and $age$ but I rather want a non-linear one. I just need a linear approximation for $f$, as I want to implement it in Gurobi

Comment: Gurobi's new version 11 does support a variety of common nonlinear functions. You can choose between global optimization and automatic piecewise-linear approximation. (Of course, whether this feature is useful for your particular application will depend on the form that $f$ takes.)

Answer (score 1):

One approximation possible is to use the tangents of $f(x)$. Assuming you are minimizing $f(x)$, introduce a new variable $z$ to approximate $f(x)$ over a given set $A$ and use constraints:
\begin{align}
z &\ge f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)\quad &\forall a \in A \\
&= -e^{-a}(x-a)+e^{-a} \quad &\forall a \in A\\
&=-e^{-a}x+e^{-a}(1+a) \quad &\forall a \in A
\end{align}